# Program to pull the network logs from Cilium to Hubble

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, google-kubernetes-engine, cilium

Anyone help me how to get/pull network logs from [Cilium](https://cilium.io/) using [Hubble](https://cilium.io/blog/2019/11/19/announcing-hubble/) in Kubernetes. [ Google Kubernetes Engine GKE].

I am not able to find an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide a lot of details on your question .

Assuming you are interested in the flow logs and you are talking about [Hubble](https://docs.cilium.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/hubble/), you can pretty much install the [Hubble CLI](https://docs.cilium.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/hubble/#inspecting-the-cluster-s-network-traffic-with-hubble-relay)  and follow what's in the rest of that doc and [this](https://cilium.io/blog/2019/11/19/announcing-hubble/#flow-visibility).

✌️

Comment: I need to get network logs using CILIUM API, without using hubble...

Comment: Please clarify your question. or ask another question